# bash wait for process in process substitution even if command is invalid

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I'm trying to write a utility script `errpipe` with a simple api that runs `stderr` through a filter. At first I tried to implement it using bash's process substitution feature.

```
#!/bin/bash

com="$1"
errpipe="$2"

$com 2> >(1>&2 $errpipe)
```

The problem with this is that the output looks strange when `com` does not exist.

If I type

```
sh-3.2$ ./errpipe foo cat
```

I get

```
sh-3.2$ ./errpipe foo cat
sh-3.2$ ./errpipe: line 6: foo: command not found
@
```

with `@` representing the cursor. In other words, the shell prompt was printed too early. I suspect this is because the main shell script is not waiting for the process substitution process to complete. Throwing in a `wait` at the end of the script doesn't seem to fix the problem.

I'm open to a solution that uses `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh` or possibly some crazy `awk` feature. I think I know how to wire this together using something like C or Perl that exposes a richer API for manipulating processes and file descriptors, but I'd like to avoid using it unless there isn't an alternative.

---

One solution that "almost works" is to use the fact that `$$` is not changed when the shell forks and to lob a signal at the parent when errpipe is finished.

```
#!/bin/bash

com="$1"
errpipe="$2"

$com 2> >(1>&2 $errpipe; kill -SIGUSR1 $$)

while true; do
    sleep 60
done
```

This fixes the original problem but a) is ugly and b) prints `User defined signal 1: 30` before terminating even if I have a signal handler for SIGUSR1 and c) will loop forever if the process responsible for sending a SIGUSR to the parent dies somehow.

Comment: You can avoid the problem by checking if `$com` exists. `if [ -x "$(type -p "$com")" ]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, in `bash` like in `ksh` (where the feature comes from), the processes inside the process substitution are not waited for.

for a `<(...)` one, that's usually fine as in:

```
cmd1 <(cmd2)
```

the shell will be waiting for `cmd1` and `cmd1` will be typically waiting for `cmd2` by virtue of it reading until end-of-file on the pipe that is substituted, and that end-of-file typically happens when `cmd2` dies. That's the same reason several shells (not `bash`) don't bother waiting for `cmd2` in `cmd2 | cmd1`.

For `cmd1 >(cmd2)`, however, that's generally not the case, as it's more `cmd2` that typically waits for `cmd1` there so will generally exit after.

`zsh` will wait for `cmd2` there (but not if you write it as `cmd1 > >(cmd2)`, use `{cmd1} > >(cmd2)` instead as [documented](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-process-substitution)).

`ksh` doesn't wait by default, but lets you wait for it with the `wait` builtin (it also makes the pid available in `$!`, though that doesn't help if you do `cmd1 >(cmd2) >(cmd3)`)

`rc` (with the `cmd1 >{cmd2}` syntax), same as `ksh` except you can get the pids of all the background processes with `$apids`.

`es` (also with `cmd1 >{cmd2}`) waits for `cmd2` like in `zsh`, and also waits for `cmd2` in `<{cmd2}` process redirections.

`bash` does make the pid of `cmd2` (or more exactly of the subshell as it does run `cmd2` in a child process of that subshell even though it's the last command  there) available in `$!`, but doesn't let you wait for it.

If you do have to use `bash`, you can work around the problem by using a command that will wait for both commands with:

```
{ { cmd1 >(cmd2); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat; } 4>&1
```

That makes both `cmd1` and `cmd2` have their fd 3 open to a pipe. `cat` will wait for end-of-file at the other end, so will typically only exit when both `cmd1` and `cmd2` are dead. And the shell will wait for that `cat` command. You could see that as a net to catch the termination of all background processes (you can use it for other things started in background like with `&`, coprocs or even commands that background themselves provided they don't close all their file descriptors like daemons typically do).

Note that thanks to that wasted subshell process mentioned above, it works even if `cmd2` closes its fd 3 (commands usually don't do that, but some like `sudo` or `ssh` do). Future versions of `bash` may eventually do the optimisation there like in other shells. Then you'd need something like:

```
{ { cmd1 >(sudo cmd2; exit); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat; } 4>&1
```

To make sure there's still an extra shell process with that fd 3 open waiting for that `sudo` command.

Note that `cat` won't read anything (since the processes don't write on their fd 3). It's just there for synchronisation. It will do just one `read()` system call that will return with nothing at the end.

You can actually avoid running `cat` by using a command substitution to do the pipe synchronisation:

```
{ unused=$( { cmd1 >(cmd2); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&-); } 4>&1
```

This time, it's the shell instead of `cat` that is reading from the pipe whose other end is open on fd 3 of `cmd1` and `cmd2`. We're using a variable assignment so the exit status of `cmd1` is available in `$?`.

Or you could do the process substitution by hand, and then you could even use your system's `sh` as that would become standard shell syntax:

```
{ cmd1 /dev/fd/3 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cmd2 4>&-; } 4>&1
```

though note as noted earlier that not all `sh` implementations would wait for `cmd1` after `cmd2` has finished (though that's better than the other way round). That time, `$?` contains the exit status of `cmd2`; though `bash` and `zsh` make `cmd1`'s exit status available in `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` and `$pipestatus[1]` respectively (see also the `pipefail` option in a few shells so `$?` can report the failure of pipe components other than the last)

Note that `yash` has similar issues with its process *redirection* feature. `cmd1 >(cmd2)` would be written `cmd1 /dev/fd/3 3>(cmd2)` there. But `cmd2` is not waited for and you can't use `wait` to wait for it either and its pid is not made available in the `$!` variable either. You'd use the same work arounds as for `bash`.

Comment: You can just do `cmd1 > >(cmd2) | cat`, just like how cat waited for fd3, cat will wait for fd1. Also, when doing `cmd1 > >(cmd2) 3>&1`, it's incorrect to say cmd2 will have its fd3 open. It doesn't, only cmd1 will have its fd3 set to fd1. cmd2 is unaffected, so the crazy redirection tree doesn't actually end up touching cmd2 at all, hence why it doesn't do anything. All that matters is piping into cat, and cat will wait for cmd1's file descriptors to close.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone But with `cmd1 > >(cmd2) | cat`, all the output of `cmd1` would go through `cat`! The point here is only to use `cat` for synchronisation. It otherwise doesn't do anything. I can't find `cmd1 > >(cmd2) 3>&1` anywhere in this answer.

Comment: For the command `{ { cmd1 >(cmd2); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat; } 4>&1`, I was referring to the claim `That makes both cmd1 and cmd2 have their fd 3 open to a pipe.`. Only cmd1 will have fd 3 open. The given solution uses fd 4 to hop over the cat and print it out, and used fd 3 to keep cat alive. That's not necessary, doing `cmd1 > >(cmd2) | cat` solves the problem at the same level of efficiency, but avoids the complicated `3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat; } 4>&1`. cat's job is to hook input to output, so the fd 4 hack isn't needed.

Comment: You used `cmd1 >(cmd2)` as opposed to `cmd1 > >(cmd2)`, my bad, but `| cat` still solves it for both. I'm not actually sure how it works though, because if `cmd2` is `sleep 1 1<&- 2<&-`, it still waits until completion, even though sleep 1 has no output pipes. However, if i use `date` instead of `cat`, it ends immediately. I'm trying to test it, but I'm supposing that the subshell spawned by the pipe for `cmd1 >(cmd2)` only closes when cmd1 and cmd2 both exit, which makes sense since cmd2 being a subshell of `cmd1 >(cmd2)`.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone, in `{ cmd1 >(cmd2); } 3>&1`, we're redirecting a command group so the redirection applies to all processes started within. Try for instance `{ echo >(ls -l /proc/self/fd); } 3> /dev/zero`. Again `cmd1 >(cmd2) | cat` makes the whole output of `cmd1` (and `cmd2` with `bash`) go through the pipe to `cat` which is not what we want. In my approach, `cat` does just one `read()` system call which reads nothing but doesn't return before both `cmd1` and `cmd2` terminate which is the whole point of the exercise.