# /dev/stderr in systemd service

Tags: systemd, stderr

I'm writing a service which should start LTE connection.

But the utility I'm using to connect (sakis3g) is writing to `/dev/stderr`, which is not available in systemd and the log is full of

```
Cannot create /dev/stderr: No such device or address
```

Is there some way to work around it?

Changing the utility script/binary is unfortunately not an option.

EDIT: Here is the service:

```
[Unit]
Description=LTE
After=syslog.target network-online.target
Before=openvpn-client@client
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/opt/mav/LTE/
ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set wwan0 down
ExecStart=/opt/mav/LTE/sakis3g connect -g --sudo
ExecStop=/opt/mav/LTE/sakis3g disconnect --sudo

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And it works in this state. But when I start `sakis3g` with `-g` flag for more verbose debug output, then the `stderr` errors appear.

Comment: You should provide more information about your `.service` file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there was no stderr, you wouldn't see the error.

Here, the error is about not being able to *open* the `/dev/stderr` file, which on Linux is a symlink to the actual file that is open on the fd 2 (while on other systems, opening /dev/stderr is like doing a `dup(2)`).

The problem here is likely that fd 2 is open on a socket (inet TCP, Unix stream or other) and you can't `open()` a socket file.

If you run:

```
sudo lsof -aU +E -d 2
```

On a system using `systemd` you'll notice that fd 2 of most services is a unix domain stream socket to `systemd-journald`.

As a work around, you may be able to start it as:

```
bash -o pipefail -c '{ /opt/mav/LTE/sakis3g connect -g --sudo 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | cat >&2 3>&-; } 3>&1'
```

That is make stderr a pipe (to `cat`) instead of a socket, `cat` forwarding what it receives on the pipe to the original stderr (the socket), and make sure we preserve the exit status of the command with the `pipefail` option.

In any case, the source of that `sakis3g` is available and that [`sakis3g` init file](https://github.com/Trixarian/sakis3g-source/blob/e43f2cc0354e508d3e089730a7246ae69377e329/src/sakis3g) is a bash script, that happen to do:

```
echo text >> /dev/stderr
```

instead of:

```
echo test >&2
```

It's even got a few `> /dev/stderr` instead of `>> /dev/stderr` which is even more wrong. It has no `tee -a /dev/stderr | other cmd` which would have been a legitimate use of `/dev/stderr` and would also not work with stderr on a socket, so it's easily fixable.

You may want to let them know of the problem by raising an issue at https://github.com/Trixarian/sakis3g-source/issues

Comment: For reference, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1212756. Now this behavior is documented by systemd, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue trying to `tee` to stdout inside a service. While it's not the OP's exact issue it *is* called out by the other answer as being a "justified use of `/dev/stderr`", so I feel like it's worth posting here in case somebody from the future needs it.

Namely I had the following:

```
command1 | tee /proc/$$/fd/1 | command2
```

In this case, `/proc/$$/fd/1` is always the shell's `/dev/stdout`, so it normally works in pipelines. It still has the same issue though of refusing to open the socket.

The solution I came up with is to swap the `tee` around with a process substitution:

```
command1 | tee >(command2)
```

**This isn't quite there yet**, because now Bash won't wait for `command2` to exit. To fix that, we can use the method from [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388530/545134):

```
{ { command1 | tee >(command2); } 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat; } 4>&1
```